# Is it possible to make Realm as observer?

Tags: realm, observer-pattern

Realm will observe webservice, and will be observable for UI.

```
protected <T> void subscribe(Observable<T> observable, Observer<T> observer){
        Subscription subscription = observable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .subscribe(observer);
        configureSubscription().add(subscription);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reactive Pattern, Presenter

first call from `resume()`:

```
public void fetchCompanies(Context context) {

    unsubscribeAll();
    if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
        subscribe(mCompanyViewListener.getCompanies(), this);
    } else {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();


        realm.where(Company.class).findAll().asObservable()
                .map(new Func1<RealmResults<Company>, Observable<Result<Company>>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<Result<Company>> call(RealmResults<Company> companies) {
                        Result<Company> companyResult = new Result<>();
                        companyResult.setValue(companies);
                        return Observable.just(companyResult);
                    }
                }).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Action1<Observable<Result<Company>>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Observable<Result<Company>> companyResult) {
                subscribe(companyResult, CompanyPresenter.this);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

second, when there is observable on service

```
@Override
public void onCompanies(Result<Company> companies) {
    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.insertOrUpdate(companies.getValue());
    realm.commitTransaction();

    mCompanyAdapter.addCompanies(realm.where(Company.class).findAll());
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Unsubscribe

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unsubscribeAll();
    }
```

Comment: When do you Unsubscribe?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, onDestroy is called

Comment: Just making sure you don't forget :P consider using `executeTransaction()` instead of `begin/commit`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, 'begin/commit' is simplier

Comment: Execute handles `cancelTransaction` in case of Throwable

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, ok now I see some advantages. I would consider it later. Thank you